# How to add a new value to existing object in array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, tsx

How can I add a value to an object in the array `persons`?

The value I want to add is `lastname` and variable `id` is the id of the object the value should be added to.

- Any help is appreciated!

---

```
const lastname = 'Jackson';
const id = 2;

const persons = [
    {
        id: 1
        firstname: 'Mary',
        lastname: 'Jackson'
    },

    {
        id: 2
        firstname: 'Ash'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one-liner to update it without mutating the original array:

```js
const updatedPersons = persons.map(p => p.id === id ? {...p, lastname} : p);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
persons.forEach(person => {
    if(this.id === person.id) person.lastname = this.lastname
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the array and add a condition to check if id matches `person.id` then add `lastname` to that person object. If you don't want to change the original array go for `.map()` else `.forEach()`
With `.forEach()`:

```
persons.forEach(person => {
  if (person.id === id) {
    person.lastname = lastname
  }
})
```

With `.map()`:

```
const newPersonsArr = persons.map(person => {
  if (person.id === id) {
    return {
      ...person,
      lastname
    }
  }
  return person;
})
```